# Contiki compile error, " ERROR: address 0x820003 out of range at line 1740 of..."

Tags: process, compiler-errors, contiki

I started to use contiki operating system with atmel atmega128rfa1. 
I can compile my example, but the hex file is bad. The error is:
 ERROR: address 0x820003 out of range at line 1740 of ipso.hex (i am not using IPSO, just i kept this name).

When I compile in linux system the code is program size is 27804 byte and the data is 4809byte.

When I compile in windows the program is 28292 and the data is 4791.

I use only one process and one etimer, I would like to turn on and off 1 led.
the makefile consinst of:
`

```
TARGET=avr-atmega128rfa1
CONTIKI = ../..
include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include

all: 
make -f Makefile.ipso TARGET=avr-atmega128rfa1 ipso.elf 
avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom ipso.elf ipso.hex 
avr-size -C --mcu=atmega128rfa1 ipso.elf `
```

i can't program the controller. What is the problem?

thank you.

Comment: so it fits if you compile in Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Special sections in the .elf file start above 0x810000 and must be removed when generating a hex file for programming a particular memory, e.g.

```
$ avr-objdump -h webserver6.avr-atmega128rfa1

webserver6.avr-atmega128rfa1:     file format elf32-avr

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .data         00001bda  00800200  0000e938  0000ea2c  2**0
              CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  1 .text         0000e938  00000000  00000000  000000f4  2**1
              CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  2 .bss          000031a6  00801dda  00801dda  00010606  2**0
              ALLOC
  3 .eeprom       00000029  00810000  00810000  00010606  2**0
              CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  4 .fuse         00000003  00820000  00820000  0001062f  2**0
              CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  5 .signature    00000003  00840000  00840000  00010632  2**0
              CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
```

So,

```
avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom -R .fuse -R signature ipso.elf ipso.hex
```

alternately, only copy the desired sections:

```
avr-objcopy -O ihex -j .text -j .data ipso.elf ipso.hex
```

Comment: I also had similar problem. My pre/Post build section had:   
-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom -R .eesafe $(TARGET_OUTPUT_FILE) $(TARGET_OUTPUT_FILE).hex
avr-objcopy --no-change-warnings -j .eeprom --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 -O ihex $(TARGET_OUTPUT_FILE) $(TARGET_OUTPUT_FILE).eep.hex

You second command worked for me. So I replaced it as 
avr-objcopy -O ihex -j .text -j .data $(TARGET_OUTPUT_FILE) $(TARGET_OUTPUT_FILE).hex  
Everything works, But I get many lines with stderr> #. What could be the reason?
stderr> avrdude.exe: writing flash (11674 bytes):

stderr> Writing | 
stderr> ##

Answer (score 0):

```
avr-objcopy --change-section-lma .eeprom=0
```

this works for me