# Avrdude .hex with Fuses

Tags: avr, avrdude, winavr

I have used a makefile to build my code and I have produced an ELF file.

To make it understandable for my attiny85, I usually use `avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom -R .fuse main.elf main_all.hex`. I get a hex file containing fuse settings. I flash the hex file with `avrdude -p t85 -c avrispmkII -P usb -U flash:w:main_all.hex`.
 I am using an avrispmkII connected via a working and tested SPI.

This time I got an error.

```
ERROR: address 0x820003 out of range
```

I guess because I've played in the code with fuses that this is the problem. According to [Contiki compile error, " ERROR: address 0x820003 out of range at line 1740 of..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745732/contiki-compile-error-error-address-0x820003-out-of-range-at-line-1740-of),
I've noticed that you can make avrdude create a hex without fuses.

```
avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom -R. Fuse main.elf main_ohne.hex
```

This has also worked and now lets the attiny85 flash completely normally.

Now the real question.

How do I still get the fuses on the attiny85?

Is there any way to see which fuse I am setting how, before I set the fuses? I ask explicitly before, because I have no experience in flashing with 12V (HV) and this arvmkII synonymous not true (Yes, I should look in the data sheet whether he can).

My main concern is to get the fuses on the attiny. I am a graduate electrical engineer who is programming in the spare time. So I'm fine with overprivileged links and the magic command.

(Rough translation from the [German original](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41577923/1))

Comment: Deine Fragen müssen in Englisch sein. (Your questions must be in English)

Answer (score 3):

You can set the fuse bytes on the command-line of avrdude. [example](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude_6.html)

There are only 3 fuse bytes on the attiny: low, high, and extended. They can be found on p. 148 of the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf).

Just compute the fuse setting as a hex number and include -U switches like

```
-U efuse:w:0xff:m  -U hfuse:w:0x89:m  -U lfuse:w:0x2e:m
```

for the extended, high, and low fuses.